# Symfony 3.3 - Entity Manager injection into services with multiple database?

Tags: symfony-3.3

I have recently added a new database to my Symfony 3.3 application.
Then my services with injected entity manager are no longer working and return the following error:

> Cannot autowire service "RouterBundle\Utils\RoutersUtils": argument
>   "$em" of method "__construct()" references class
>   "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager" but no such service exists. Try changing
>   the type-hint to one of its parents: interface
>   "Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface", or interface
>   "Doctrine\Common\Persistence\ObjectManager".

So my config.yml file is now like :

```
# Doctrine Configuration
doctrine:
    dbal:
        default_connection: router
        connections:
            router:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_router_name%'
                user: '%database_router_user%'
                password: '%database_router_password%'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci
                    row_format: DYNAMIC
            app:
                driver: pdo_mysql
                host: '%database_host%'
                port: '%database_port%'
                dbname: '%database_app_name%'
                user: '%database_app_user%'
                password: '%database_app_password%'
                charset: utf8mb4
                default_table_options:
                    charset: utf8mb4
                    collate: utf8mb4_unicode_ci

    orm:
        default_entity_manager: router
        entity_managers:
            router:
                connection: router
                mappings:
                    RouterBundle:  ~
                dql:
                    string_functions:
                        # Match agains should have the path to the Sha1 class created in the previous step
                        SHA1: RouterBundle\Extensions\Doctrine\Sha1
            app:
                connection: app
                mappings:
                    AppBundle: ~
```

One of my service like :

```
<?php

namespace RouterBundle\Utils;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;

class RoutersUtils
{

    protected $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

...
```

and my services.yml ( I tried to add this arguments but doesn't work)

```
...
RouterBundle\Utils:
    public: true
    arguments:
        - '@doctrine.dbal.router_connection' 
...
```

Any idea how to inject the correct Entity Manager?
Can I also inject entity manager by default using the "default_entity_manager: router" parameters in teh config file ?

Thanks for the help !

Pierre

Comment: Maybe inject ManagerRegistry? https://matthiasnoback.nl/2014/05/inject-the-manager-registry-instead-of-the-entity-manager/

Answer (score 1):

You cannot autowiring by using the `EntityManagerInterface`  if you have many managers. You  will have to pick the right manager in your service definition for each service.

```
RouterBundle\Utils:
    $em: '@your_entity_manager_service'
```

PS : You should consider upgrading to sf3.4 as 3.3 is not maintenaited anymore. It also comes with local binding, which will be really useful for what you want to do.

See: 
https://symfony.com/blog/new-in-symfony-3-4-local-service-binding

Comment: Hi Fabien, thank you so much.. I almost there but I get this error : The service "RouterBundle\Utils\RoutersUtils" has a dependency on a non-existent service "doctrine.orm.entity_manager.router". Is your solution for 3.4 only or it works for 3.3 ?

Comment: ( even if I try doctrine.orm.entity_managers.router or doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager )

Comment: it works with $em: '@doctrine.orm.entity_manager' and I don't understand why !!

Comment: PS : you are right, 3.4 has default arguments injections. It'd be quite useful in my case...

Comment: Actually, I did not test the service name. If you use many managers, you may find their services names using `debug:container` command

Comment: My solution works on 3.3, but with the correct service name, I just edited to avoid confusing

Comment: Actually you can autowire `EntityManagerInterface` but it injects the default EntityManager for you.